# Lost icons (firefox,notepadpp,fzilla) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons

Okay the deal is simple. I lost the icons and see that white icon instead of them in the taskbar which is really annoying. Tried reinstalling Firefox, no use. (Tried checking the firefox icon in the app folder (program files), but same situation there, no icon).

OS: Windows 7 x64 up-to-date, every update installed

(Maybe related: I installed my PC with a wrong account name. Renamed it. That rename caused much headache since Windows messes with my user folder, bla bla. Now I made a new user, called "S" and I'm using this ever since that incident.)

Comment: Are you saying that the icons for Firefox and Notepad++ don't display in the taskbar while they are running, or do you have them pinned to the taskbar?

Comment: I have them in quick launch. I can see their icons THERE. But on the taskbar (when they are running) and in the progam files (the .exe files) are blank, white icons.

Comment: Here is a picture about it: http://shiki.hu/p/problem.jpg

Comment: Another info, FILEZILLA is the same. What the?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding the Icon Cache. This involves deleting the IconCache.db file in the Local AppData folder and rebooting.

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-rebuild-icon-cache-in-windows-7-to-repair-icons/

Answer (score 0):

Okay not really an answer. Reinstalled Windows. (Nowadays I feel like back then with XP without SP. Reinstall after reinstall.)